# Adding dictionary in plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, plist

I need to add items in my plist (organizations.plist)
My plist is organized in the following way:
I have a root dictionary, and in this one, I have others dictionary...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>Address</string>
        <key>City</key>
        <string>City</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Description</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>name</string>
        <key>Coordonates</key>
        <string>40.781208, 35.219622</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I try to add dictionary by the following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"organizations" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableDictionary *newItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newItem setValue:@"address" forKey:@"address"];
[newItem setValue:@"City" forKey:@"City"];
[newItem setValue:@"32.067487, 34.785156" forKey:@"Coordonates"];
[newItem setValue:@"Description" forKey:@"Description"];
[newItem setValue:@"Name" forKey:@"Name"];

NSArray * allKeys = [plist allKeys];
int count = [allKeys count] + 1;
NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
[plist setObject:newItem forKey:strFromInt];
[plist writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
[plist release];
NSLog([plist description]);
```

the log is good the `newItem` has been added, but if I open the organizations.plist file in xCode I see that nothing has been added

Comment: You can not wright files the main bundle, it is read only.

Comment: Firstly copy plist  in document directory and then do your operations as initially your plist file will be in bundle which will be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all copy your `plist file` at `document directory`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                 YES);
            plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"organizations.plist"];


            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]){
                NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"organizations" ofType:@"plist"];
                BOOL sucesss = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:plistPath error:&error];
                if (!sucesss) {
                    NSLog(@"Exception fail to copyItemAtPath : %@",[error description]);
                }
            }
```

Then when you need to write file you have to fetch `plist` from `document directory` and need to `update` there.

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *newItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newItem setValue:@"address" forKey:@"address"];
[newItem setValue:@"City" forKey:@"City"];
[newItem setValue:@"32.067487, 34.785156" forKey:@"Coordonates"];
[newItem setValue:@"Description" forKey:@"Description"];
[newItem setValue:@"Name" forKey:@"Name"];

NSArray * allKeys = [plist allKeys];
int count = [allKeys count] + 1;
NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
[plist setObject:newItem forKey:strFromInt];
[plist writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
[plist release];
NSLog([plist description]);
```

Comment: thank you , but I 'm not sure I understand   where a get the folderPath?

Comment: Please check updated `answer` i removed that line.

Actually that line is not needed..

Comment: Ok good but if i open my organization.plist from any text edit I see that nothing has been added.

Comment: @user3460154 You can not write to Bundle resources , they are ready only. read the comments on your question . Abhishes's answer is not writting to Bundle file rather it creates a copy of your bundle file to Documents directory of the app and modify ( read , write , update ) the file there . 
That is the reason you don't see any changes to Bundle file .

Comment: You can not modify bundle file. So i copied first on document directory and then used that to write.

if you want to see the updated plist flie then you must have to see plist file which is copied on document directory.